# Least number principle for IOpen fragment of Peano Arithmetic

Tags: theories-of-arithmetic

Is it possible to prove the least number principle in IOpen fragment of Peano Arithmetic, i.e. having induction only for Open formulas?

Comment: What is the "least number principle"?

Comment: The least number principle for *open* formulas is provable in IOpen. This follows immediately from Shepherdson's characterization of models of IOpen (though I don't quite remember whether it is explicitly stated in his paper).

Comment: @Wojowu https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Induction,_bounding_and_least_number_principles

Comment: And to complete Emil's point, of course we aren't going to get the full least number principle for all other formulas, since that is equivalent to the induction principle of PA. One should view the least number principle simply as an alternative way of expressing induction. The least number principle asserts that whenever there is an instance, there is a least instance, but this is essentially the contrapositive of strong induction.